# How to turn arrays into a string using the join method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I am new to JavaScript and was trying this exercise:

Make two versions of your random insult generator: one that
uses the + operator to create the string, and one that creates
an array and joins it with " ".

The first generator I did this way but how to do the second?

```
var randomBodyParts = ["Face", "Nose", "Hair"];
var randomAdjectives = ["Smelly", "Boring", "Stupid"];
var randomWords = ["Fly", "Marmot", "Stick", "Monkey", "Rat"];
var randomAnimalBodyParts = ["Tail", "Feelers", "Wings", "Trunk"];
var randomBodyPart = randomBodyParts[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
var randomAdjective = randomAdjectives[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
var randomWord = randomWords[Math.floor(Math.random() *   randomWords.length)];
var randomAnimalBodyPart = randomAnimalBodyParts[Math.floor(Math.random() * randomAnimalBodyParts.length)];
var randomInsult = "Your " + randomBodyPart + " is more " + randomAdjective + " than a " + randomWord + "’s" + " " + randomAnimalBodyPart + ".";
randomInsult;
"Your Face is more Boring than a Rat’s Tail."
```

Comment: `"foo " + "bar " + "baz"` vs `["foo", "bar", "baz"].join(" ")`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join

Comment: @georg 
Thank you!
`var randomInsult = ["Your", randomBodyPart, " is more ", randomAdjective, " than a ", randomWord, "’s", randomAnimalBodyPart, "."].join(" ");`

Comment: @Mathletics
I have already read it but was unable to solve it...